# (Dis)continuity of function in $R^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

> $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} a+2x^{2}-b(y-c), & x^{2}>2+x\wedge y<6\\
>  3+cx-y, & else \end{cases}$$
>
> $f(x,y)$ is continuous on $R^2$ if $a=-3, b=1, c=2$

I think it's true: insert the values of a,b,c into the function:

$$\begin{cases}
-1+2x^{2}-y, & x^{2}>2+x\wedge y<6\\
3+2x-y, & else
\end{cases}$$

Now, we need limits of both parts to be equal on the "border" defined by $y=6 \wedge x^2-x-2=0$, i.e. $x = 2; -1$

As both parts that defines our function are continuous on their intervals, it suffices just to insert values for checking the equality of the limits.

At $x=2 \wedge y = 6$

$$-1+2x^2-y = 3 + 2x -y$$

$$7 = 7$$

At $x=-1 \wedge y=6$

$$1= 1$$

So, our function is continuous. But the answer is supposed to be $f(x,y)$ is discontinuous. Where did I mistake?

Comment: The border between the two regions is not two just points.

Comment: How do I check limits along the line?

Comment: You only need to find a single example of discontinuity.  Guess and check?

Comment: I find it strange to write something like $A > B < C$... are you sure?

Comment: @Gaffney, no idea :(

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini, it looks like you missed $\wedge$ inside what you called "B".

Comment: @Yaldc  Trouble at the guessing or the checking step?

Comment: @Gaffney, at guessing.

Comment: Ok, so $\wedge$ is an *and* not a *min* as I thought!... :-)

Answer (score 0):

The *border* is $((x=-1 \vee x=2) \wedge y\le 7) \vee ((x\ge 2 \vee x\le -1) \wedge y)=7$. So, for example, you can check that the function is not continuous at point $x=3,y=7$

Comment: So, I need check not only $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0; y \rightarrow y_0}$ where $x_0; y_0$ are taken from intersection of "borders", but also $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0}$ and $\lim_{y \rightarrow y_0}$, right? (I simplify a bit: by "lim" I mean the whole equality: lim of the 1st part = lim of the 2nd part)

Comment: You have to carefully identify what is the boundary of the set $\{(x,y) \colon x^2>2+x \wedge y<6 \}$. In this case you find that this boundary is composed by four half-lines.